# File conflict pop up removed for only one folder

Tags: filesystem, filemanager

When I want to copy paste some files already in a destination directory, Ubuntu asks if I am sure I want to replace the original file as follows:

[image]

I would like to keep this pop up in my system except for one folder and all its subfolders.
Meaning, for the given folder "Presentation" and all its subfolders, I would like that Ubuntu does not show the File conflict pop up and always applies "Replace". I know how to do that system wide, but is it possible to do it only for "Presentation" and no where else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no feature to selectively disable this confirmation dialog.